# Stream processing lots of stuff to OVA

Tags: bash, sed, stream, pipe

So one of our developers needs me to batch a bunch of information and process it into an OVA to be presented back for download. This is an easy process using the long method (ie writing to the filesystem), but the developers want a cleaner, streamlined solution that will scale better. They have therefore requested that I stream the entire processes which is proving difficult. Can someone please give me some direction. Here are the steps that need to be accomplished:

1. Get input from webserver (Webserver will pass these as stream eventually.)

   - Random password
   - XML file
2. Modify boot script on file system (ie insert random password generated by server)
3. Create ISO of XML file and boot script
4. Calculate the SHA1 sum of ISO
5. Append SHA1 sum of ISO to manifest file in OVF directory
6. Create OVA from OVF directory

Here is an example directory structure (I outlined this in / just for simplicity)

```
/--
  |
  |--ISO/
  |   |
  |   |--boot.sh (Where the random password gets inserted)
  |   |--config.xml (This is handed from the web server. Needs to stream from server)
  |
  |--OVF/
      |
      |--disk.vmdk
      |--ovf.xml
      |--manifest.mf (Contains SHA1 of all files in OVF directory)
      |--boot.iso (This file will exist once created from ISO directory)
```

Here is what I have so far (I'll explain the issues afterwards. Yes... there are a lot of issues):

```
cat /ISO/boot.sh | sed "s%DEFAULT%RANDOM%" | mkisofs /ISO/* | echo "SHA1(boot.iso)= " && sha1sum >> manifest.mf | tar -cvf success.ova /OVF/*
```

***NOTE***
In boot.sh there is a variable set to DEFAULT like this (Just for testing purposes):

```
PASSWORD="DEFAULT"
```

***NOTE***
This is what a line in the manifest file should look like:

```
SHA1(boot.iso)= 5fbc0d70 BLAH BLAH BLAH a91c9121bb
```

So I've never tried to write an entire script in one stream before. Usually I write to the filesystem a lot as I go. The first issue I see with this is that sed is replacing the string, but what it's piping over to mkisofs will not be used as mkiosfs is just going to make an iso of what it finds in /ISO. I dont even know if you can pass something like that to mkisofs. Piping is sometimes weird to think about.

Next, I think mkisofs is ok because I didnt specify a file output, therefore it should output to stdout which will be passed to sha1sum, but and here is the next problem I see. I need to append some additional text to the file before the SHA1 sum gets added which kinda interrupts the stream.

Finally, the last problem I see is how to pass everything to be tar into OVA without writing to the filesystem first (writing to manifest.mf).

Oh and the last BIG problem which I should have mentioned first is the config.xml file. Right now im dealing with it as just a file. The dev guys want to pass it to this script as a stream as well. I dont have a clue how to handle that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. These concepts are a little beyond my knowledge.

Thanks!

***UPDATE 12/11/13 2:11PM EST***

Testing each part individually right now. Will report findings below soon.

***UPDATE 12/11/13 2:14PM EST***

The following works:

```
cat /ISO/boot.sh | sed "s%DEFAULT%RANDOM%"
```

and produces the following output:

```
RANDOM="RANDOM"
```

Exactly as expected.

You are correct NeronLeVelu, I will have to come back later and look at sed more carefully when real random passwords are being generated. ie. Making sure proper characters are escaped. Right now though, I'm just testing the logic. I will worry about regex and escaping later. We have not even decided on random password yet. It's only temporary and will most likely be alphanumeric.

Moving onto next part. Still not sure how to take the output from sed (stdout) and use it to include in ISO creation without actually creating a file that gets written to the file system. It may not be possible without writing to file system. More to come soon

Comment: quite a handful. I'd recommend breaking up your problem into really simple tests to prove to yourself, for instance 'if you can pass something like that to mkisofs'. If it won't work with the simplest case you can think of, then you have to solve that first, before you try to make it complicated. Repeat as needed. +1 for well fmtd and explained question, but I won't have time to try and parse all of that. Good luck!

Comment: Will help if you can define what your "devs" mean by scale better. Just faster? and/or a threads-like approach (multiple jobs at one time), and/or ?? ..... Just read the part about XML file as a stream. Again, another reason to break this down as much as possible and try to prove that the basic idea can work. If you can do `cat file.xml | stream_process` and the `stream_process` can parse out what is the start and end of an xml file, then you have a hope. Good luck.

Comment: They want to stream this because it may need to scale at some point to lots of requests. Remember, this is designed to custom package an OVA for a customer. Once packaged, it presents it for download. Needs to be streamed to help scale to lots of requests.

Comment: Sed have "some" limitation for several task and in your case be sur that the Password is not a regex pattern meaning something else. In replacement section of s//, you cannot have & \ and the pattern delimiter that are not escaped. (no problem with alphanumeric value)

Comment: Back from lunch. I will continue to append updates to the post above. Thanks for help.

Comment: Burning discs? We're not burning any discs. Are you referring to some code that is also involved in creating ISO's? Otherwise, I don't believe this is related.

Answer (score 1):

```
# for the password if it contain & \ and separator used in your sed (default is /)
Password4Sed="`echo \"${PASSWORD} | sed \"s/[\\/&]/\\\\&/g\"`"


# no need of a cat with a sed
sed "s/DEFAULT/${Password4Sed}/"/ISO/boot.sh > /tmp/mkisofs.input
```

Treat rest from this input and put some test to validate each step like empty crc value or mkisofs.input. This will help at runtime when production error occur

Comment: Hmm, ok, trying to digest your partial answer. Thank you for the help.