# $(shell [foo]) in Windows

Tags: windows, shell, makefile, ros

I've got a makefile (a file called 'Makefile' which is run by cmake in Linux, but works in Windows via nmake I believe and needs to be run in VS command prompt.)

And most of the 'sample' ones I can see are just one line (and the rest appear to be stuff I don't 'yet' understand and then this same one line.

```
include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
```

(in the terminal rospack find [package] returns the path to said package, and cmake.mk is obviously the file it wants to include)

My problem is, that this appears (to me at least) to be written for use in a Linux system (which basically the entirety of ros, the program I'm working with, was) and in Windows this appears to just try to be

```
include /cmake.mk
```

(which unsurprisingly doesn't work)

Basically I need to know how to do the same thing in windows, generally in a 'dynamic' way, as it will only cause more problems down the line if I get this working by hard-coding the directory path and then it breaks because its not set properly some time in the future)

So I guess if this isn't possible or is particularly hard, a way of hard coding it would be a stopgap.

I tried:

```
include C:\[directory]\cmake.mk
```

but it seems to have issues with the ':'

I'm trying to work with Windows, because later in my project I'll be needing to use another program (for i90 robot) for which we only have Windows support.

OK, so apparently it acts differently if the file is actually in the folder.
as in

```
include C:\[directory]\cmake.mk
```

Errors with

```
C:\[directory]\cmake.mk not found
```

if the file isn't there, and

```
fatal error U1034: syntax error : separator missing
```

if it is

While this doesn't really seem to impact on the original problem, I guess it indicates I'm trying to do something funky windows doesn't like.

Comment: how did you get a windows environment to run cmake? Do you have a Unix work-alike installed, Cygwin or MingW? I'd be surprised if there is a way to do this without installing at least some unix work-alike utilities. (I'll be happy to be shown wrong). Why not install a Linux VM or the above on your windows machine and build your stuff there? See if the tag `cmake` has more followers that `makefile` and if so, tag your post with that to increase the number of people looking at your question. Good luck!

Comment: Which do you mean? Start at the beginning, did you open a cmd.exe window and just `cd projectDir....` and then `cmake`? (And edit that info into your question above, don't make people have to read thru 10 back and forths in comments ;-) )... I'd really be surprized if that worked, unless you've been given a special Windows machine to work with for the project? You need to get more "eyes" on your question. Add the programming language for the project. if there is a high followers tag for the `ros`, add that, use your 5 tags to the best benefit. Good luck!

Comment: Sadly this is one of the ways I'm out of my depth.
I believe it uses Nmake (through the VS2012 command prompt), but it's called through 'winros_make' (which may be different again)

I probably can get this to work on a Linux VM, but I started on windows, because I didn't want to add complexity with communicating between this (used for controlling the drones) and the windows based software use for the i90 robot.

Sadly I've spent long enough on it now, that I wont have time to change tact between now and christmas break.

but thanks, I'll have a look at tags, and look into MingW or a VM again

Comment: Ah ok, add a tag for `nmake`, that should give you a lot of eyes. Also, search web, there may be a specfic website for support for your project we're you'll either see this has been solved already, or you'll get the experts on that project to help you. (Christmas, bad timing, but you've still got a few days :-) )! Finally, look closely thru the files for doc and README.TXT that may give you hints on how to build in the windows env.  Good luck.

Comment: Doesn't `nmake` use `!INCLUDE`?

Comment: Honestly I have no clue, like I said I'm just going off what I can work out from the files I have (which as far as i know without exception were written to be loaded by cmake in linux, as I can't find much documentation on any of this of any use)

would this be (not)INCLUDE? or is is just a different syntax? for include??

Comment: Ouch, `nmake` ~50 followers. I'd replace with `cmake`, `gmake`, `make`, which ever has the highest number of followers. ALSO better look for the `ros` specific website. Again, consider editing your question to show what you have tried so far (don't answer here). FINALLY, read my comments about another question today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526217/stream-processing-lots-of-stuff-to-ova#comment30689352_20526217 . You need to start splitting this up into small easily testable pieces to see if this can work in windows and MS2012. Can you even get  'hello world' to compile?. Good luck.

Comment: Got to go. good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you'll never get a single makefile that does much of anything complicated that will work both with standard UNIX-style make (such as GNU make from GNU/Linux) and also work with nmake.  Nmake is a completely different beast.

As an aside, it's confusing that your makefiles here are called "cmake", because cmake is an actual program, distinct from make (and nmake).  I'm assuming, though, from the context that the use of the term "cmake" here doesn't refer to the actual cmake utility.  Which is too bad, because if it did use cmake things would be simpler for you.  Maybe.

It's not clear exactly what your requirement to use nmake is, though.  If you laid out your real requirements, it would be a lot easier for us to advise you.  For example, you say you need to use a "another program" which runs only on Windows.  What does this program do, exactly, and how will you need to use it?  Does it provide libraries that need to be linked with the "ros" code?

Basically, your simplest way forward is to obtain a UNIX-like environment, including tools like GNU make, for your Windows system.  There are two main choices: Cygwin, which provides a completely POSIX infrastructure including shell, compiler, etc. which are ports of the GNU environment to Windows but require a POSIX layer, and MinGW, which has various GNU tools that run more or less natively on Windows.

However, if you MUST use Visual Studio as your compiler, for example, then these will be much more difficult to integrate.